# Kubuntu freezes during update when trying to download adobe installer

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, flash, freeze

I'm updating to the latest version of Kubuntu, three times running now it's made it to the part where it goes to download the Adobe Plugin Installer and it freezes. I waited for 3 hours and saw no network traffic.

I've run this command twice:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And it sticks at the same place. Is there something I'm missing? Is there perhaps a way to exclude the Adobe bits from the update?

Answer (score -1):

Try to purge the package

```
sudo apt-get purge adobe-flashplugin
```

And then reinstall via

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```